# Angular Material V14 table will not accept an image

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Material 14.1 in my Angular 14 app.

I've introduced a table and all was populating fine until I try to add a column that I want to add an image to.

I have the following:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="ImageUrl">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> imageUrl </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img [src]="{{element.imageUrl}}" /> </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

but I receive an error stating: **Element 'img' cannot be nested inside element 'table'**

Looking around stack overflow and other sites a suggested solution seems to be to change the  <mat-cell element to:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img [src]="{{element.imageUrl}}" /> </td>
```

However I then receive the same error but for the 'td' element instead.

Has anybody managed to display an image in a material table at this version?

Thank you

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz example?

Comment: Isn't it related to the fact that you are using curly braces interpolation in [src] and you shouldn't?

Comment: @TJ96 I tried without the the {{}} but it made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone else that may hit this issue. I've noticed that if I do the following, thought it still complains that 'Element img cannot be nested inside a table' it still Renders fine:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img width="45" height="45" src="{{element.imageUrl}}" /> </mat-cell>
```